# Spring jpa query using group by clause

Tags: spring-data-jpa

How to write a Spring jpa query using group by clause  without using @Query annotation?

Answer (score 2):

seems its not possible as there is no method name support for it - judging by "Supported keywords inside method names" table in docs http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.7.0.RELEASE/reference/html/

Query annotation is made just for that, use it for custom solutions.